# Best way to communicate with non-WCF service

Tags: wcf, web-services, soap

I have a non-WCF service that i need to communicate with. I have the WSDL of the service, and it uses WS-Security 1.0 with UsernameToken policy.

Example of the header:

```
<S11:Envelope xmlns:S11="..." xmlns:wsse="...">
<S11:Header>
...
<wsse:Security>
 <wsse:UsernameToken>
 <wsse:Username>username</wsse:Username>
 <wsse:Password>password</wsse:Password>
 </wsse:UsernameToken>
</wsse:Security>
...
</S11:Header>
...
</S11:Envelope>
```

What is the best way to communicate with this service?

If i use WCF, making the header look like what i need for the UsernameToken is going to be a problem from what i know, right? How can i do that?

On the other hand, i can make a non WCF proxy even though it's kind of obsolete.

What's the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the service uses ssl then you can have your wcf config like this:

```
<customBinding>
  <binding name="NewBinding0">
    <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />
    <security authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport">
      <secureConversationBootstrap />
    </security>
    <httpTransport />
  </binding>
</customBinding>
```

if the service does not use ssl then you should use [ClearUsernameBinding](http://webservices20.blogspot.com/2008/11/introducing-wcf-clearusernamebinding.html)

Comment: And using a non-wcf proxy? Is it a bad idea?

Comment: in your case this is also a valid idea. if the xml body is very simple you could get away without serialization at all, just have a request template and push the username headers to it. if you need serialization I recommend to use wcf rather then manually maintaining a serialization assembly. but even if you use wcf you could not configure it to do any security and push the username header yourself via a custom message inspector.

Comment: I ended up using a non wcf proxy and wse 3.0. Thanks for your help, i marked your answer as the right one.